# The below error occurred after running the command ionic(5) serve

Tags: ionic-framework

TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "path" argument must be of type string. Received type undefined
    at validateString (internal/validators.js:112:11)
    at Object.join (path.js:375:7)
    at noopServiceWorkerMiddleware (D:\Learning of React+ReactNative\myApp\node_modules\react-dev-utils\noopServiceWorkerMiddleware.js:14:26)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\Learning of React+ReactNative\myApp\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (D:\Learning of React+ReactNative\myApp\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:317:13)
    at D:\Learning of React+ReactNative\myApp\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (D:\Learning of React+ReactNative\myApp\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
    at next (D:\Learning of React+ReactNative\myApp\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
    at launchEditorMiddleware (D:\Learning of React+ReactNative\myApp\node_modules\react-dev-utils\errorOverlayMiddleware.js:20:7)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\Learning of React+ReactNative\myApp\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)
    at trim_prefix (D:\Learning of React+ReactNative\myApp\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:317:13)
    at D:\Learning of React+ReactNative\myApp\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:284:7
    at Function.process_params (D:\Learning of React+ReactNative\myApp\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:335:12)
    at next (D:\Learning of React+ReactNative\myApp\node_modules\express\lib\router\index.js:275:10)
    at handleWebpackInternalMiddleware (D:\Learning of React+ReactNative\myApp\node_modules\react-dev-utils\evalSourceMapMiddleware.js:42:7)
    at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (D:\Learning of React+ReactNative\myApp\node_modules\express\lib\router\layer.js:95:5)

Answer (score 5):

I found a fix, seems the problem stems from react-scripts 3.3.x series. In package.json I changed

```
"react-scripts":"3.3.0"
```

to

```
"react-scripts":"^3.4.0"
```

then run `npm i` and `ionic serve` and it works.

More info here https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/8490